# no visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'indexPathforSelectedRow]'

Tags: uitableview, segue

I'm a newbie. Be gentle. I have a table/detail almost done. I get this error ("No visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'indexPathforSelectedRow') on this line: indexpath = [mytableview indexPathforSelectedRow]; in my segue function. I searched through all the other topics and tried their solutions. I am not good enough at this to know just how to adapt their code to mine. So, how do I fix the error?

```
// test for what cell was selected here then send it to the view
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetailsSeg"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexpath =nil;
        NSString *titlestring =nil;

        indexpath = [mytableview indexPathforSelectedRow];
        titlestring = [titlearray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

        [[segue destinationViewController] setTitlecontents:titlestring];
    }
}
```

Comment: Found it (thanks to Phillip)! There's a typo in for. It should be: indexPathForSelectedRow

Comment: For future reference, you should use suggestions always. that'll minimize your syntax mistakes.

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Comment: I didn't. but it's because of you were not clear about which kind of error. Compile-time or run-time. You should be more specific next time u ask a question. Review the question 2-3 times before posting it.

Comment: Oh. Okay. THanks. I am a newbie here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lowercase `f`.
I think it should be `indexPathForSelectedRow`